# Scope rules in C: Nested blocks

Tags: c, gcc, scope, nested, language-lawyer

I have the following nested function:

```
int main()
{
   int a, b, c;
   a = 10;
   int foo()
   {
       int a, b, c;
       //some more code here
   }
   // some more code here
}
```

Now, I need to assign the variable `a` that belongs to `foo()`, with the value of the variable `a` that belongs to `main()`.  Basically, something like `foo.a = main.a` is what I'm looking for.

Is there any way of doing this kind of assignment? I read through scope rules [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm) , but didn't find anything I could use in this situation.

I know that using a nested function is not advisable, but I'm working on preexisting code, and I don't have permission to change the structure of the code.

How do I proceed?

Comment: are you really going to use a nested function? this is supported as GCC extension, not standard C.

Comment: Well, this is preexisting code and I don't have permissions to modify the code structure.

Comment: How to proceed? pass a b c in main as pointers to foo and rename a b c in foo

Comment: Is there any way to proceed without changing the names of a b c?

Comment: You proceed by getting rid of the nested function.  If you're authorized to make any changes, you can fix that blotch.  And you can't use scope resolution in C; there is no such concept.  Why is changing variable names so anathema?  What is your real problem?

Comment: gcc extensions only fills one purpose, and this is to tease the C standard committee. "Look what we can do!" They had some impact on how the C99 and C11 standards turned out. But that's about the only use of them, they should be avoided, as most of them are completely superfluous features anyhow.

Answer (score 6):

Keeping apart the *nested function* part, AFAIK, `C` does not provied any *direct* way to access the *shadowed* variable.

**Primary Advice:** Do not use this approach. Always use separate variable names for inner scopes and supply `-Wshadow` to `gcc` to detect and avoid possible *shdowing*.

However, just in case, you have to use the same variable names for inner and outer scope and you have to access the outer scope variable from the inner scope, your best bet is to (in this very order, inside the inner block)

- declare a pointer, assign the address of the outer variable to it.
- declare and define the local variable.
- use both.

---

Note: As a general word of advice, please try not to write *new* code (I understand the *maintainance* part) in this manner. It is both hard to manage and hard to read.

Comment: He just have to rename the inner variables.. then, both outer and inner ones can be used.. i don't understand y pointer is required here...

Comment: @A.M.D if that can be done, then this very queustion itself becomes irrelevant, isn't it? I guess, OP's target is to achieve the goal _without_ changing the variable names. However, I'll add a bit mentioning your point to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Comment: But if u can declare a pointer, u definitely can rename :-) ... just my thought.. no offence! :-)

Comment: @A.M.D None taken. Rather I appriciate you for making  your point. Thanks much. Added a clarification, hope it makes my stand clear. :-)