# C Error: declaration shadows a local variable -- Won't let me repeatedly replace the value of my float variable

Tags: c, syntax-error, cs50

I'm working on the CS50 problem set 1, problem Greedy.c and I can't get around this error.

```
greedy.c:26:15: error: declaration shadows a local variable [-Werror,-Wshadow]
    float cents = cents - q;
          ^
greedy.c:16:11: note: previous declaration is here
    float cents = roundf(change * 100);
```

What am I missing? Given the error, I'm wondering if I didn't think to include a piece of syntax when declaring the float "cents". I'm a noob, so forgive any inefficiencies/redundancies in my code.

```
int main(void)
{
float change;
do
{
    printf("Change: ");
    change = get_float();

}
while (change < 0);

float cents = roundf(change * 100);
int coins = 0;
int q = 25;
int d = 10;
int n = 5;
int p = 1;

while (cents >= q)
{
    coins++;
    float cents = cents - q;
}
while (cents >= d)
{
    coins++;
    float cents = cents - d;
}
while (cents >= n)
{
    coins++;
    float cents = cents - n;
}
while (cents >= p)
{
    coins++;
    float cents = cents - p;
}

while (cents == 0)
{
    printf("Total coins dispensed: %i\n", coins);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `float cents = cents - q;` --> `cents = cents - q;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this question because _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: Note: `float cents = cents - q;` does not assign any value to existing `cents`, it creates a new block scope variable altogether.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Guessing missing headers? :)

Comment: Also: [a reference, (my contribution there)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30588599/2173917)

Comment: @KeineLust `cents = cents - q;` --> `cents -= q;`

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Nice plug of your good answer.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `float cents =` with `cents =` in your `while` loops.

Currently you're trying to declare a new variable `cents` which *shadows* the existing one. Technically this is valid C, perhaps your compiler (thankfully) has this warning set to an error?

Note that you could optimise much of your logic to O(1) using *integer division* and careful checking with your debugger. Repeatedly subtracting from a value is crude, can get you into hot water if you work with floating point types, and is unnecessarily computationally expensive. (Although can be a good step to getting things working.)

Finally, do you need that last `while` loop? Presumably you *always* want to output the coins dispensed, not an infinite number of times when `cents` is zero?

Comment: Also the bottom while loop is weird. Either it doesn't execute at all or it is infinite.

Comment: @JeremyP: Good spot, if you don't mind I've nicked that.

Comment: Of course you can nick it, I wouldn't have mentioned it if I wanted it to be secret .

Comment: I am very good looking.

Comment: That's obvious from your picture. What breed are you?

Comment: Birman. Blue point.